# Passing array as hint in string export?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to pass an array as a hint in string export, something like this:

```
extends Node


var things_list=["thing_1", "thing_2", "thing_3"]
export(String,*things_list) var current_thing=things_list[0]
```

#### why am I doing this?

I want to reuse the `things_list` & to do so I have to tediously write all the same values twice,
once in this list itself & once in `export` like this:

```
extends Node


var things_list=["thing_1", "thing_2", "thing_3"]
export(String,"thing_1", "thing_2", "thing_3") var current_thing=things_list[0]
```

this becomes really annoying with longer lists,
So is there anything like [`...array` in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
or something like [`*args` in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)? (as shown in the first example)

or are the values somehow stored in the export variable itself?
maybe like `current_thing.export_hints[1] #thing_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are stored internally and there is no scripting access. And no, the parser does not understand any syntax for an array in `export` (nor array spread elsewhere for that matter).

However, there is something similar. You can define an `enum`:

```
enum things {thing_1, thing_2, thing_3}
export(things) var current_thing = things.thing_1
```

As you might remember, if you have an `enum`, you have a `Dictionary`. So you can still get the list of things like this:

```
var things_list = things.keys()
```

However, the `enum` will be of `int`, not of `String`. Which I don't know if it will be an issue. You can still get the corresponding `String` like this:

```
var things_list = things.keys()
print(things_list[current_thing])
```

---

And, of course, your other option is to use `_get_property_list`. It is not overly complicated:

```
var things_list := ["thing_1", "thing_2", "thing_3"]
var current_thing:String = things_list[0]

func _get_property_list() -> Array:
    return [
        {
            "name": "current_thing",
            "type": TYPE_STRING,
            "hint": PROPERTY_HINT_ENUM,
            "hint_string": PoolStringArray(things_list).join(",")
        }
    ]
```

Comment: note: using `_get_property_list()` requires `tool` mode